# Can I make function `extern "c"`?

Tags: c++, c, lua, ffi, luajit

I have some cpp files, and I want to combine them with LuaJit using FFI.

But the problem is that, I have to add `extern "c"` symbols for almost every function to make it possible for FFI to access them.

Is there a simpler way to make this done?

Comment: you can group all the functions in a single extern C block. Isn't that enough?

Comment: The cpp files are not created by myself, I know nothing except their functions. I just want to use them through Lua.

Comment: First of all, did you check that all your functions are `extern "C"`-ready? I.e. do they use only C types (no references, no classes etc.)? `extern "C"` only turns off name mangling.

Comment: @Serhio So not all functions can be mark `extern "C"`? Then it would be really difficult if I want to use opensource cpp files for my Lua project.

Comment: What do you expect?  Miracles?   The whole point of `extern "C"` is to provide an interface to C code, by disallowing features that are incompatible with C.   If Lua requires a C interface, it is not possible to use features specific to C++ across that interface.   If you want to use opensource C++ files in your project, you need to provide an `extern "C"` set of functions which are compiled using a C++ compiler, and use capabilities of C++ in their implementation.

Comment: @ZehuiLin You can mark with `extern "C"` whatever function you want, but it doesn't mean that all marked functions will be C-compatible.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I read the code, and found that I can add one `extern "C"` block for it. It seems working now.

Answer (score 0):

Several functions can be placed inside a single `extern "C"` block. This allows you to type `extern "C"` only once for each header file.

```
extern "C" {
    void function1();
    void function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is non-portable, you could implement a function signature and generates the [Mangled name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++) using the name mangling protocol to find the symbol name for FFI.

Gcc and Clang on Linux use the Itanium C++ ABI Name Mangling Rules, which can be found [here.](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#mangling)

On Windows, MSVC uses a non-documented name mangling scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Define a simple, minimal, wrapper API and export it:

```cpp
// NOTE: Exported functions do heavy parley and medical-research leveraging C++ under the hood (and only and the hood).
extern "C" {
  void achieve_world_peace(void);

  void treat_cancer(void);
}
```